# How to run/debug a java application inside LSP-MODE / DAP-MODE directly, without stopping in the begining?

Tags: java, emacs

When I run dap-debug, it shows my mainclass (java file) and waits do strike the "start image on the center-top" (get the same result with "dap-continue" command). Is a way to run direcly (without starting debugging a breakpoint) and doesn't showing/opening the mainclass?

Answer (score 0):

Just change inside launch.json:
"stopOnEntry": false,